# How to add an onchange event to a select box via javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got a script where I am dynamically creating select boxes.  When those boxes are created, we want to set the `onchange` event for the new box to point to a function called `toggleSelect()`.

I can't seem to get the syntax right to create the `onchange` event.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  It doesn't throw an error, but doesn't work, either.

```
  col = dataRow.insertCell(0);
  var transport_select = document.createElement('select');
  transport_select.id = transport_select_id;
  transport_select.options[0] = new Option('LTL', 'LTL');
  transport_select.options[1] = new Option('FTL', 'FTL');
  transport_select.onChange = function(){toggleSelect(transport_select_id);};
  col.appendChild(transport_select);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add

```
transport_select.setAttribute("onchange", function(){toggleSelect(transport_select_id);});
```

[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SetAttribute)

or try replacing `onChange` with `onchange`

Comment: Thanks!  Changing it from "onChange" to "onchange" fixed it.

Comment: some versions of IE are known to have troubles with setAttribute, so the transport_select.onchange = function(){...} approach seems more fail-safe ;)

Comment: this gave me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`

Answer (score 67):

Here's another way of attaching the event based on [W3C DOM Level 2 Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/):

```
  transport_select.addEventListener(
     'change',
     function() { toggleSelect(this.id); },
     false
  );
```

Comment: and the handler's first param is the `event`.

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me after lots of struggling with `setAttribute("onchange",function(){}`

Answer (score 14):

replace:

```
transport_select.onChange = function(){toggleSelect(transport_select_id);};
```

with:

```
transport_select.onchange = function(){toggleSelect(transport_select_id);};
```

---

on'**C**'hange    **>>**    on'**c**'hange

---

You can use [addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628882/2835520) too.

Comment: More generally for getting option value or id: `select_element.onchange = function(){console.log(this.id + ": " + this.value);};`

Answer (score 11):

```
yourSelect.setAttribute( "onchange", "yourFunction()" );
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You need to describe your answer. Also, you need to answer the question itself. user77413 is asking 'How to add an onchange event to a select box via javascript?' and also asks in their post 'Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?'. You need to address these in your answer.

Comment: This answer is short and effective.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me out of the above.

Comment: This is even better with `yourSelect.setAttribute( "onchange", "yourFunction(this)" );`

Comment: It was 2020, well past time to put binding events with HTML attributes to bed, along with table-based layouts and answers with no text. Use `addEventListener` to separate behavior from structure and allow for more than one event listener per event and element.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using prototype.js then you can do this:

```
transport_select.observe('change', function(){
  toggleSelect(transport_select_id)
})
```

This eliminate (as hope) the problem in *cross-browsers*